# Array[0] but still data in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm debuging my code with Chrome DevTools and I have a strange ocasion.
I have an array which which contains data but console shows Array[0]
When I try to access it, it gives me an arror `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Let me show you the details:
There is an Object I call from console "quick_chat", when I expand this object there is another Object called data, which shows like data: Array[0], but I'm still able to expand it where there is another object with the Id of my chat.

[image: chatdebug]

as you see here data is Array[0] but with data in it.
How can I access it with console? any suggestions?

Comment: _Array[0]_ in console means a zero-length array. The property you can see is called `3SWA8h0clcAi` and is not an index of the array `data`.

Comment: I know that and I tried refreshing my object to see if it still there and it is

Comment: Which indicates that an object will be a more appropriate container for this type of data.

Comment: @Mpa4Hu can you make a test case which produces same behaviour for us?

Comment: How are you trying to access it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That data is stored in a property of the array, and would be accessed using:

```
quick_chat.data["3SWA8h0clcAi"]
```

Comment: @duskwuff this does not explain the _SyntaxError_.

Comment: @PaulS. yeahh, I was trying it with different syntax, my bad

Comment: still, can you expand your answer by what you mean it's stored in the propery, I mean, why array[0].. you mean this way it's not an array but Object?

Comment: @Mpa4Hu Every _Array_ (in _JavaScript_) inherits from _Object_ and therefore is an _Object_, however, it has special extensions that mean if you use non-negative integers as property names it behaves in a special way. This doesn't mean you can't do other things that an _Object_ can do. However, if you're not using it for the special bits _Array_ provides, it's better to use _Object_ directly because that's what you're using it as.